# import csv into mongodb using mongoimport to insert unique data with out update

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I am importing csv data into mongoDb using **mongoimport** command.

`mongoimport -h="127.0.0.1" --port=27017 --db=myapp -c=test--type=csv --mode=upsert --upsertFields=name,place  --file=test.csv --columnsHaveTypes --fields="name.string(),place.string(),designation.string()"`

**Problem:**

I have already have the below data into mongoDB

| Name | Place | Designation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | XYZ | Engg |

And in the csv file, I have below data

```
name,place,designation
ABC,XYZ,
```

when I use the **mongoimport** command with **--mode=upsert** , the **designation** column in the DB is replaced by **null**.

But I want to either skip this record while importing or not update(or keep) the existing designation column.

Can anyone provide the pointers on this ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What happens if you use `mongoimport`'s [`--ignoreBlanks`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#std-option-mongoimport.--ignoreBlanks) option?  Or perhaps even the [`--parseGrace`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#std-option-mongoimport.--parseGrace) option?

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong, ignoreBlanks will be on record level , not on column level.

Comment: IDK for sure.  I was hoping you'd find out and let us know.

Comment: Did you try `--mode=merge`?

Comment: yes, it is replacing the Designation - 'Engg' with 'null'. Hence, merge is not an option.

Comment: I assume `--ignoreBlanks` didn't do what you want.  What happens with `--parseGrace=skipField`?